# Help lawn recover from yearly plowing/snow fall

Tags: grass, snow

During the winter (zone 5) we have a plow truck push snow off our driveway onto the yard. Due to the amount of possible snow we can get in a year they usually leave push back 10' from the driveway's end. Over the winter the pile grows taller and the push back gets closer. We haven't seen a "bad" winter but we still have gotten within 5' of the driveway edge.

What can be done to help the lawn in this plow/push area to comeback quicker each year?

Most of the lawn is Dutch/white clover, with some other shade friendly grasses. I seldomly use salt as the driveway is south facing and gets good sun. I am looking for something that will help the lawn bounce back quickly after a few months be being scraped by the plow, and then a prolonged "mud season" as the resulting pile melts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mud season suggests drainage to remove the excess water more efficiently.

Driving on it to plow the snow back suggests traffic grid of some sort to limit grass (clover, etc.) damage.

Traffic grid (of the "lawn reinforcement" variety) is some type of lawn reinforcement with holes for grass to grow through and a grid type structure to limit and spread the load of vehicle traffic - plastic and concrete are the most common materials I'm aware of and have seen employed for the purpose. There are many different manufacturers. Some are square holes, others are circular, others are hexagonal, the idea is basically the same. The grid is embedded in the lawn (or the grid is placed, and soil is filled into it and seeded.)

Comment: can you expand on what traffic grid is?

Comment: I've seen traffic grid used to make a wheelchair accessible garden. I want to say it was a plastic honeycomb structure. Allowing soil/plants to grown wile the chair's weight it taken by the structure. I assume there may be a larger version for truck weight. Sometimes called "Lawn Savers" or "Lawn Grid".